# Bad output passing integers from parent to child

Tags: c, pipe, parent, child-process

My assignment is to pass integers entered on the command line and pass them through a pipe from parent to child where the integers can be added together and returned to the parent via reaping. All of my integers turn into the number 4 in the child, and the reaped value for sum always returns as the number 1.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static int  toChild[2];
static int  toParent[2];
static int  input;
static int  output;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     status;
    int     nInts = argc;
        // set up pipe
    pipe(toChild);
    pipe(toParent);
        // call fork()
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(toChild[1]);
        close(toParent[0]);
            // -- running in child process --
        int     sum = 0;
            // Receive characters from parent process via pipe
            // one at a time, and count them.
            // Return sum of numbers.
        for (int i=1; i < nInts; i++) {
            output = read(toChild[0], &input, sizeof(input));
            sum += output;
            }

        return sum;
        close(toChild[0]);
        close(toParent[1]);
        }
    else {
        close(toChild[0]);
        close(toParent[1]);
            // -- running in parent process --
            // Send numbers (datatype: int, 4 bytes) from command line arguments
            // starting with argv[1] one at a time through pipe to child process.

        for (int i=1; i < nInts; i++) {
            input = atoi(argv[i]);
            write(toChild[1], &input, sizeof(input));
            }

        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        if(WIFEXITED(status)){
            // Wait for child process to return. Reap child process.
            // Receive sum of numbers via the value returned when
            // the child process is reaped.
            printf("sum = %d\n", WIFEXITED(status));
        }
        close(toParent[0]);
        close(toChild[1]);
        return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `close` after `return`?

Comment: I was worried if it was before it would close communication too early.

Comment: I mean those `close` are never called, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you have the pipe back to the parent if you send no data along it?  That seems unnecessarily complex.  Statements after the `return` are not executed at all; they are dead code.  Fortunately, the return from `main()` exits the program, and all open file descriptors are closed when the program exits, so it doesn't matter, but it is worrying that you think there might be any utility in putting the `close()` calls after the `return`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've been coding for a few months now, but there are a lot of very basic concepts that I haven't mastered yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = read(toChild[0], &input, sizeof(input));
sum += output;
```

You are assigning the return value of `read` to `output`. This is the number of bytes read, i.e. `sizeof(input)` which is 4 on your platform. So you are always increasing `sum` by 4.

You want:

```
ssize_t bytes_read = read(toChild[0], &input, sizeof(input));
//check that bytes_read == sizeof(input) here
sum += input;
```

Also:

```
printf("sum = %d\n", WIFEXITED(status));
```

`WIFEXITED` just says whether the process exited. Use `WEXITSTATUS` to get the exit status.